# How to extract multiple dictionaries from a text file with no new line using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list, dictionary, file-io

I have a text file with the following type of data:

```
{'key1':'data','key2':'data','key3':'data','key4':{'subkey1':'data','subkey2':'data'}}, {'key1':'data','key2':'data','key3':'data','key4':{'subkey1':'data','subkey2':'data'}},
{'key1':'data','key2':'data','key3':'data','key4':{'subkey1':'data','subkey2':'data'}}
```

Please note that the quotes(' ') are also present in the text file. Each dictionary is separated by a comma and there are no newlines(\n) in the file.

I would like to extract these from the text file as a list of dictionaries.

I am very new to Python and though of reading the entire text file as a single variable using readlines() function and then separating them using pattern matching with regex.

I am unable to figure out a reliable pattern for using regex for the same.

Ultimately, it should look something like this:

```
extracted_list = [{'key1':'data','key2':'data','key3':'data','key4':{'subkey1':'data','subkey2':'data'}}, {'key1':'data','key2':'data','key3':'data','key4':{'subkey1':'data','subkey2':'data'}},
{'key1':'data','key2':'data','key3':'data','key4':{'subkey1':'data','subkey2':'data'}}]

for dict in extracted_list:
      print(dict['key1'])     #should print 'data under key1'
      print(dict['key4'])     #should print 'sub-dictionary under key4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want to extract dicts from a text file, then you can do:

```py
import json

extracted_list = []

with open("dicts_file") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        extracted_list.append(json.loads(line))
```

`json.loads()` creates a dictionary (or list) from a json string. This is then stored in `extracted_list`.

I hope this helps.